# Incorrect path when using path module in gulp task

Tags: node.js, path, gulp

A typical gulp task:

```
gulp.task('copy', function() {
  gulp.src('src/css/**/*').
    pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/css'));
});
```

**Output:** `dist/assets/css/**/*`

The same gulp task with the [path module](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html):

```
gulp.task('copy', function() {
  var src = path.join(path1, path2), // src/css/**/*
      dest = path.join(path3, path4); // dist/assets/css

  gulp.src(src).
    pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});
```

**Output:** `dist/assets/css/src/css/**/*`

Can you explain me why path is incorrect in this case and how to fix it? (The only thing that came to my mind is to use base option for gulp.src)

Comment: How exactly are  your path1, path2, etc. variables initialized?  Please edit your question to show those.

Comment: `var path1 = 'src/css', path2 = '**/*'` and so on. It doesn't matter now. I found the solution. It turned out that `gulp.src` requires an absolute path, so we have to use `path.resolve()` instead of `path.join()`.